# vue.js + django rest framework

Tags: django, vue.js, framework

Доброе время суток, возникло несколько вопросов: 
"Какие плюсы даёт переход с стандартного рендера шаблонов силами фреймоворка django на рендер с помощью vue.js и api запросов получения данных?"
"Какие +/- у этих способов? Есть ли улучшение ttfb или ускорение полной загрузки страницы со всей статикой? Стоит ли использовать vue.js для сайтов с 3-4 страницами по типу главная/галерея/контакты"
"Стоит ли использовать js фреймворки только для сайтов-заметок(как пример), сайтов-магазинов и тд?"

К слову, полный профан в фреймворках на js, решил ознакомиться с ними и Django Rest Framework для создания api (для опыта написал код с использованием urls/views для получения некоторых данных с гугл аналитики(аутентификация+определение нужных данных на своём сервере), что и получилось неким подобием своего api для гугл api).
Буду благодарен вводной литературе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Один из основных плюсов - намного более удобное взаимодействие с элементами на страницах.

Когда ты делаешь прототип, для тебя интерактив не играет особой роли, но когда проект растёт, ты понимаешь что тебе нужно больше `JavaScript` кода. Если ты используешь `jQuery`, то у тебя на каждую страницу начинает заводится свой собственный `.js` файл. В этом случае, у тебя много лишнего и дублируемого кода, да и когда дело заходит чуть дальше, чем до простого сабмита формы при помощи AJAX, то код становится сложнее поддерживать.

Полноценный `js` фреймворк даёт тебе потенциал использовать JavaScript по максимуму и с удобством, даже когда вначале кажется что тебе это не нужно.

2) Минусы заключаются в том, что у тебя появлятеся больше забот. У тебя в проекте появляется на одну, причём весьма серьёзную технологию больше. Тебе придётся тестировать свой `fontend`, тебе придётся поддерживать актуальность библиотек.

Так же, тебе будет сложнее с деплоем и в разработке. Если ты не используешь `docker`, то в процессе разработки тебе придётся поднимать `Vue` и `Django` одновременно, следить за `traceback` в двух вкладках терминала. Если станешь деплоить всё это отдельно, то со стороны `Django` ещё и придётся позаботится о [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). Если ты используешь `docker`, то тебе достаточно будет использовать отдельный контейнер для `Vue` как это сделано [здесь](https://github.com/vchaptsev/cookiecutter-django-vue).

Если ты вздумаешь иметь много логики на фронтенде, например авторизация/регистрация через [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/), или работа со [Stripe](https://stripe.com/), то разработчикам которые придут в твой проект, будет сложно понять архитектуру и тестировать бекенд, который так сильно разделён с фронтендом.

SEO. У тебя возникнут проблемы при `CSR`. Тебе придётся настроить `prerender` или `SSR`, но я бы порекомендовал использовать [Nuxt](http://nuxtjs.org/)

Тебе в любом случае будет труднее и как минимум не привычно.

Из плюсов: в последствии проще сделать мобильное приложение используя, например, `[NativeScript][3]` или десктопное приложение, используя [Electron](https://electronjs.org/).

Вообще, плюсов масса, но и минусы вначале будут.

3) Скорость загрузки. Если вкратке, то первая загрузка будет сильно дольше при использовании `Vue`. Скорее всего твой `bundle.js` будет весить >1 Мб. А ещё у тебя будут стили и картинки, которые можно грузить асинхронно, но всё же. Последующие же страницы будут загружаться быстрее. Кешировать нужно только 1 файл `css` и 1 файл `js` на весь твой проект, в этом, однозначно, плюс.

При использовании шаблонов, твоя скорость загрузки будет примерно одинаковой на всех страницах, ты закешируешь основной `js`, но на каждой новой странице у тебя будут встречаться дополнительные подключённые файлы, которые тоже нужно будет кешировать. В этом минус.

[Здесь](https://medium.com/walmartlabs/the-benefits-of-server-side-rendering-over-client-side-rendering-5d07ff2cefe8) достаточно интересная статья на эту тему.

4) Используй где хочешь. Но для сайта в 3-4 страницы, лично я не стал бы заморачиваться.